# Super multiple properties from parent

Tags: javascript

I am working through the intermediate javascript course on codecamp, and my next assignment is to use super. It asks to use super with multiple properties, i.e.

```
class School {
  constructor(name, level, numberOfStudents) {
    this._name = name
    this._level = level
    this._numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name
  }
  get level() {
    return this._level
  }
  get numberOfStudents() {
    return this._numberOfStudents
  }
  quickFacts() {
    console.log(`${this.name} educates ${this.numberOfStudents} students at the ${this.level} school level`)
  }
  static pickSubstituteTeacher(substituteTeachers) {
    const randomNum = math.floor(math.random() * substituteTeacher.length - 1)
    return substituteTeachers[randumNum]

  }
  set numberOfStudents(newNumberOfStudents) {
    if (typeof newNumberOfStudents) {
      return this._numberOfStudents = newNumberOfStudents
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid input: numberOfStudents must be set to a Number.')
    }
  }
}

class PrimarySchool extends School {
  constructor(name, numberOfStudents, pickupPolicy)
  super(name, 'primary', numberOfStudents)
  this._pickupPolicy = pickupPolicy
}
get pickupPolicy() {
  return this._pickupPolicy
}
```

On this line, I get

```
super(name,'primary', numberOfStudents)

> super(name,'primary', numberOfStudents)
  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token super
```

How do I initiate super to include the three properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten some curly brackets

```
class PrimarySchool extends School {
  constructor(name, numberOfStudents, pickupPolicy){
    super(name, 'primary', numberOfStudents)
    this._pickupPolicy = pickupPolicy
  }
  get pickupPolicy() {
    return this._pickupPolicy
  }
}
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please.